# iOS In App Purchase Error - This Item is no longer available

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

In my app, I have IAP for subscriptions. Until now it worked perfectly and now we are getting this error when trying to purchase. In SandBox, this works fine.

> This Item is no longer available

Comment: Go to iTunesConnect -> My apps -> Select your application -> Go to features tab. In the list of IAP check if your product id has "Approved" status.

Comment: @llb Yes, it is

Comment: Next suggestion is to check if all your IAP are available in all regions. If yes, then check your product ids for typos.

Comment: @llb checked those. Nothing changed of those.

Comment: Check this thread then: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7750618

Comment: @fewlinesofcode nothing worked. I can purchase one subscription. Problem is only with one subscription plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by few days after we agreed to the new contracts in Apple Developer Account. I guess the issue has been caused by it.